# Microsoft Graph API: List sign in of users assigned any Dynamics license

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to list sign in of users who are assigned any of the MS Dynamics licenses in order to get the usage report. As it looks the MS Dynamics license grants access to several apps and if any user is signing in any of that apps he/she is assumed to be effectively using the license.
Is there any way we can get the information using Graph API?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out, to my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to list  signed in users using the Dynamics license with Graph API.  [M365 Usage Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide) only show Dynamics 365 Customer Voice Activity not usage of apps using the license. You might want to use the [Power Platform Admin Centre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/power-platform-admin-center) to manage Dynamics 365 apps.

Would you consider filing a feature request on the [M365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so this can be looked into?

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions,